# ramda equivalent for rotate

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given a rotate function like the one below, which rotates the array a set number of slots.

Is there an equivalent Ramda.js function or composition that will do this rotation?

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
function rotate(arr, count) {
    arr = arr.slice();
    while (count < 0) {
      count += arr.length;
    }
    count %= arr.length;
    if (count) {
      arr.splice.apply(arr, [0, 0].concat([].slice.call(arr.splice(arr.length - count, count))));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**example**

```
rotate(test, 2) // -> [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a point-free one liner which takes the count first and the data second, consistent with ramda's composable style:

```
const rotate = pipe(splitAt, reverse, flatten);
```

Of course you can always `flip(rotate)` to get a data first version.

### UPDATE

Sorry, I read too fast and assumed the normal, left-wise direction for the rotation (eg, as it is in ruby).  Here's a variation of the idea that does what your original does:

```
const rotate = pipe(useWith(splitAt, [negate, identity]), reverse, flatten);
```

Comment: it's great, but it rotates in the opposite direction to the original answer, giving [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2] instead of [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], the split argument needs to be negative to obtain the same result. Great Answer though!

Comment: Truly beautiful

Comment: What about using unnest instead of flatten? Unnest just removes one level of nesting while flatten makes the whole array flat, and that's not what rotate should do imo.

See example here (unnest):
https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?%0A%0Aconst%20rotate%20%3D%20curry%28%28count%2C%20array%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20pipe%28splitAt%2C%20reverse%2C%20unnest%29%28count%2C%20array%29%2C%0A%29%3B%0A%0Apipe%28%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20rotate%281%29%2C%0A%29%28%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0A%7D%29

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @donnut's answer, but includes modulo arithmetic to handle counts which exceed the length of the given list:

```
var rotate2 = function(xs, count) {
  var n = -(count % xs.length);
  return R.concat(R.slice(n, Infinity, xs),
                  R.slice(0, n, xs));
};
```

Here's a mutation-free equivalent which doesn't use Ramda at all:

```
var rotate3 = function(xs, count) {
  var n = -(count % xs.length);
  return xs.slice(n).concat(xs.slice(0, n));
};
```

Both solutions are significantly more declarative than the solution in the original post.

Comment: I like the handling of lengths larger than the original list, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function reverse(arr, count) {
    return R.concat(R.slice(arr.length-count, arr.length, arr),  R.slice(0, arr.length-count, arr));
}
```

See http://bit.ly/1G90ny8